# How do people actually pronounce "Orange"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

There are questions on ELU about the phonemic transcriptions of *orange* in both British and American English in dictionaries.

However, this being a site for linguists and all that, I thought I would indulge myself in a question about how people pronounce *orange*, in terms of what sounds they actually make and the qualities of those sounds in 'minutiae'.

What are some narrow transcriptions of the word *orange* that we might expect in standard Englishes (with a segment by segment explanation)? If you have any interesting narrow transcriptions of non-standard English varieties, also with explanations of the finer features, those would be very welcome too.

Comment: One example -- [start at 0:17](https://youtu.be/ZN5PoW7_kdA)

Comment: [Start about 0:17](https://youtu.be/82hivD7ua6Y) -- the people are speaking with what seems to me to be a British accent.

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/Pmql-zeRJqM) sounds like fairly normal American speech.

Comment: In spite of the puppet voices, [this](https://youtu.be/C0fsIMCjVkM) gives you several fairly "normal" pronunciations of "orange".  Note the range of variation, though.

Comment: Did you pick the phrase *segment by segment* as a deliberate play on *orange*? ;)

Comment: @HotLicks yep it is a south east British accent, it is how I say it.

Comment: How detailed a phonetic transcription do you want? Also, what is so particularly special about 'orange' that you're concerned about? The /ndʒ/ cluster? The vowels?

Comment: Usually they're glad I didn't say "apple."

Comment: /ɔɹndʒ/, of course. Rhymes with ... nothing?

Comment: Related: [How many syllables does "orange" have, and what regional dialects show a difference in that number?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310952/how-many-syllables-does-orange-have-and-what-regional-dialects-show-a-differe/)

Answer (score 4):

Here are the transcriptions given in J. C. Wells's *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* for *orange* :

- British English,  /'ɒrɪn*d*ʒ/, (less frequent) /'ɒrən*d*ʒ/
- American English,  /'ɔ:rən*d*ʒ/, /'ɔ:rɪn*d*ʒ/, /'ɑ:rən*d*ʒ/, /'ɑ:rɪn*d*ʒ/

In American English, /ɔ:/ corresponds to the vowel sound in w**a**r, /ɑ:/ to the sound that can be found in **o**dd.

/*d*/ can be omitted.

In AmE, the preference poll conducted by Wells for the pronunciation of *orange* gives the following results:

- /'ɔ:rən*d*ʒ/ or /'ɔ:rɪn*d*ʒ/ 80%
- /'ɑ:rən*d*ʒ/ or /'ɑ:rɪn*d*ʒ/ 20%

Comment: In British English, /ɑ:/ is not the vowel in *odd*; it's /ɒ/. We don't have that vowel in American English, which is why we're confused about how to pronounce *orange*.

Comment: @PeterShor  /ɑ:/ is Wells's conventional sign for the transcription of the sound in "odd" as pronounced in American varieties of English.  He uses /ɒ/ for the "odd" sound in his trancription of British English.  I don't think there's any confusion in how "orange" is pronounced in America, just two different ways of pronouncing it, one more common, the other less so.

Comment: @PeterShor  I've changed the answer a bit, I don't mean to use BrE as a standard.  Wells has two different systems of transcription for each variety that are clearly kept apart in the entries of his dictionary.  BrE and AmE are not described relatively to each other.

Comment: I realized you had changed your answer, which is why I deleted my second comment. You've fixed the flaw I was complaining about.

Comment: @Jim  I've checked in the LPD, both are possible in AmE, with no indication of frequency though.  I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Are you sure Wells uses /ɔ:/, not /ɔ/ for the American?

Comment: @Araucaria  He does in the 3rd edition of the LPD I have.  It's from 2008 and I don't think a 4th one has been published.